# How to programmatically clear all tables from all databases in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I found this script which does the job for clearing all the tables in one database.

```
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL'
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'DELETE FROM ?'
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'ALTER TABLE ? CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL'
GO
```

I'm not familiar with Microsoft SQL Server, at the moment I right click and run the query. I have 100 databases to clear.

How do I clear all tables from all databases programmatically?

Comment: What do you mean by "clear" all the tables? Delete all the data? Considering you should have foreign keys, this isn't a simple task.

Comment: Honestly, if you do need "clean" databases, wouldn't it be better to `DROP` them and then recreate them from Source Control?

Comment: Something is VERY VERY wrong if you need to empty the data out of every single table in over 100 databases on an instance. This is a massive red flag that you need to seriously consider rewriting most of your system or that you are trying to hack somebody. Either way what you are trying to accomplish sounds so horribly wrong it isn't even funny.

Comment: commit all databases to git - drop them all and deploy through git

Answer (score 0):

You can probably also use the undocumented `sp_MSForEachDB`, combining it with the `sp_MSForEachTable` to iterate through each `db` then through each table. You should be using `TRUNCATE` instead of `DELETE`. However, you might be better off just using SSMS to generate scripts for the database. Generate scripts, delete the old DB, generate a new empty one.

The syntax for this undocumented procedure is:

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @command
```

Example:

```
USE master
GO

EXEC sys.sp_MSforeachdb 'USE ?
IF DB_NAME() NOT IN(''master'', ''model'', ''msdb'', ''tempdb'')
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_MSForEachTable ''ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL'';
    EXEC sp_MSForEachTable ''TRUNCATE ?'';
    EXEC sp_MSForEachTable ''ALTER TABLE ? CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL'';
END'
GO
```

Comment: i was doing right click on the database drop and create to. when i ran the script it is taking over 10 minutes recreate a single database. while the script above is instant.

Comment: Personally, I would prefer truncate over delete in this instance, but dropping and recreating the database makes the most sense to me still.